# Angular- Spring Boot send string array parameters error

Tags: arrays, angular, spring-boot

My project Angular 8 and Spring Boot. Sent spring boot service attring array. But I also get an error sending from Angular.[image: Error]

Component.ts

```
personelList: Array<string> = ['Alex,'Adam','Melly'];
save() {
    this.personelService.savePersonel(this.personelList).subscribe(res => {
      if (res === 'OK') {
        this.alertify.success();

      } else {
        this.alertify.error();
      }
    });

  }
```

Service.ts

```
savePersonel(personel: Array<string>): Observable<any> {
    return http.post(apiHost + '/Personel', personel).pipe(map((data: any) => {
      return data;
    }));

  }
```

Spring Boot

```
@PostMapping(value = "/Personel")
  @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> createPersonel(@RequestParam List<String> personel) {}
```

Comment: By default content-type of http.post is application/json, and your are passing array of string

Comment: Can you give an example how exactly will it be?

Comment: `I also get an error sending from Angular`. Can you be more specific ? Can you show us the response error code and body ?

Comment: error:Bad Request   message:Required List parameter 'personel' is not present  . Error Ss added.

Comment: `this.personelService.savePersonel({personel: this.personelList})` ?

Comment: if you want to pass a list use @RequestBody and in your backend make a dto for the list

Comment: Thank you hous , worked with @RequestBody :)